# How is the path "~" determined on Windows R?

Tags: r, windows

On my R 3.6.1 on Windows 10, the path "~" is assigned to oneDrive. I want to change but I can't find out how R determines the paths to "~". E.g

`dir("~", full.names = T)` list all files in the "~" directory and gives the directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortcut `~` is a generic notion for "home" which on Unix resolves to the value of the environment variable `$HOME` -- which is not set by default on Windows.

```
> Sys.glob("~")   # Sys.glob() expands wildcards
[1] "/home/edd"
R> Sys.getenv("HOME")
[1] "/home/edd"
R>
```

So the answer to your question, really, is 'how to I set the the environment variable `$HOME` on Windows. Which depends a little on your Windows version, but is generally available in the administrative tools. Here is [one answer from SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1190364/how-to-set-home-directory-in-win10/1190369).